# Binary Search Tree print in order

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to insert something into a binary tree, and I wanted to check whats inside by using an in-order print function. An exception seems to be thrown at "print_bst_node(root->left);" that says "Exception thrown: read access violation." each time I run the program. Is there something wrong with this function?

Edit, added the insert_bst wrapper function.

```
//bst.h

    typedef struct bstNode { //pointer to the bst 
        long data;  //storing long data types from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
        List courses; //this is the list of courses 
        struct bstNode *left; //left child of the tree
        struct bstNode *right; //right child of the tree
    } *BSTNodePtr;

    typedef struct bst {
        BSTNodePtr root; //points to the root of the tree 
    } BST;

//bst.c 

    void print_bst_node(BSTNodePtr root) {
        if (root != NULL) {
            print_bst_node(root->left);
            printf("%ld ", root->data);
            print_bst_node(root->right);
        }
        else {
            printf("Nothing to see here");
        }
    }

BSTNodePtr insert_bst_node(BSTNodePtr self, long n) { 
    if (self == NULL) {
        self = malloc(sizeof *self);
        self->data = n;
        self->courses = new_list(); //creates a new linked list in the binary search tree nodes.
        self->left = self->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (n < self->data) {
        self->left = insert_bst_node(self->left, n);
    }
    else if (n > self->data) {
        self->right = insert_bst_node(self->right, n);
    }
    return self;
}


void insert_bst(BST *self, long n) { //wrapper function for insert_bst_node
    self->root = insert_bst_node(self->root, n);
} 
//main.c 

void add_to_bst(BST *self) { 
    long input = 0;

    printf("Enter student ID\n");
    scanf("%ld", &input);
    insert_bst(self, input);
    print_bst_node(self);
}
```

Comment: Make sure you haven't deleted part of your tree and left a node's left pointer pointing to the deleted subtree.

Comment: Nope, none of my main functions have anything to do with deleting anything from the tree.

Comment: Okay, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50037785/edit) your post to include the code you use to construct the tree.

Comment: Nothing wrong in this function. The problem is in some other code. Perhaps the code building the tree.

Comment: It seems you haven't properly assigned `NULL` to the leaves.

Comment: Alright I've edited to show more functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you are passing an incompatible pointer as argument to `print_bst_node()` function. The `print_bst_node()` parameter is of type `BSTNodePtr`:

```
void print_bst_node(BSTNodePtr root) {
```

and you are passing `self` to it:

```
print_bst_node(self);
```

which is a pointer to `BST` type:

```
void add_to_bst(BST *self) {
```

Instead, you should pass `self->root` to `print_bst_node()`:

```
print_bst_node(self->root);
```

The compiler must be throwing a warning message for passing incompatible pointer type.

Comment: Ah! Apologies! I forgot to include the wrapper function into the code here.

Comment: It worked! I didn't know I could modify memory locations in the parameters of a function in the main.c file.

Comment: One more blatant example of confusion created by hiding pointers behind typedefs. Note that the compiler most probably issued a warning that should have been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

The `print_bst_node` function will print an awful lot of `"Nothing to see here"` messages!

Apart from that, is seems fine, as long as we can infer... you did not provide the declaration for `BSTNodePtr`.

The problem is elsewhere:

- the node pointers `left` and `right` might not be properly initialized upon allocation or declaration
- the node pointers might not be properly updated when you insert or delete nodes from the tree.

Update your question with code for a complete example for a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Okay I've included the structs from the h file, the print_in_order function, and the main.c code

Comment: So far on the debug output, it says "Exception thrown: read access violation.
**root** was 0xCCCCCCCC.
" 
Really not sure what's wrong with my root.

Comment: @JLWK as mentionned an input example could help you answer

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a node, the node must be having all its left and right children set as `NULL` or `(void *) 0`

Answer (score 0):

When adding new nodes, you should attribute its value and then ->left ->right to NULL, or you will have problems in functions like that. Since the stop case is looking for NULL and there wont be one (it will most likely read garbish that is at that memory point).

After that the function you created is perfectly fine :)